# How To Create List From JSON Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have problem understanding arrays and loops, therefore this task is a bit confusing to me. Here's my stuff;

**JSON**

```
{
"states": [
    { 
        "name":"johor" , 
        "command":"view_johor" }, 

    { 
        "name":"selangor" , 
        "command":"view_selangor" }, 

    { 
        "name":"melaka" , 
        "command":"view_melaka" }, 

    { 
        "name":"kuala lumpur" , 
        "command":"view_kl" }, 

    { 
        "name":"penang" , 
        "command":"view_penang" }
    ]
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function(){

$.ajax({
    type        :   'GET',
    url         :   'scripts/list.json',
    async       :   false,
    beforeSend  :   function(){/*loading*/},
    dataType    :   'json',
    success     :   function(result){

                        $.each(result, function(index, val){
                            for(var i=0; i < val.length; i++){
                                var item = val[i];
                                console.log(item.name)
                                }
                        });         

                        },
   });
});
```

**My problem is I don't know how to use the loop it so that my HTML will return like this:**

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#view_johor">Johor</a></li>
   <li><a href="#view_selangor">Selangor</a></li>
   <!-- and so on, dynamically depending on json... -->
</ul>
```

I can access the data via `console.log(item.name)` and such, but I can't manipulate the data so that it will display like I wanted. I don't even know the term to use to search for questions, as I know this is like basic array stuff....Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: there are 100's of posts on this site....and many tutorials on web on how to parse json to html... do a  bit more searching

Answer (score 8, accepted):

u can do it :

```
 $(function(){

$.ajax({ 
  type : 'GET', 
  url : 'scripts/list.json', 
  async : false, 
  beforeSend : function(){/*loading*/},
  dataType : 'json', 
  success : function(result){
   var buffer="";
    $.each(result, function(index, val){ 

      for(var i=0; i < val.length; i++){ 
        var item = val[i]; 
        console.log(item.name);
        buffer+=" <li><a href='#"+item.name+"'>"+item.name+"</a></li> <li><a href='#"+item.command+"'>"+item.command+"</a></li>"; 
      } 
      $('ul').html(buffer);
    });
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Here's my console to you `Can't find variable: buffer`

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Forgot to create `var = buffer` up there.

Comment: Thanks @Vicky. I'll grow up to be a better developer thanks to you!

Comment: No! What if `item.name` contains an HTML entity?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery can create elements and append to your documents with few lines of code.

You can create an empty list like this.

```
 var mylist=$("<ul></ul>");
```

Then inside your `for` loop, for each item, do something like this

```
mylist.append($("<li></li>").text(item.name));
```

And finally append your newly built list to your document to get it displayed:

```
mylist.appendTo($("body"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should work :**

Get the json file you want to read from, make a list of items using the key and values of the json data.And finally add the list inside a ul and append it to body.

```
$.getJSON( "jsonFile.json", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val1 ) {
    $.each(val1, function(){
            items.push( "<li><a href=#'" + this.command + "'>" + this.name + "</a></li>" );     
        });
    });
    $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Comment: U r missing # in href

Comment: Maybe I should convert `items` to string first? HTML printed `[Object, Object]` five times.

Answer (score 0):

I'm checked this script and this works properly:

```
var records = {
                "states": [
                    {
                        "name": "johor",
                        "command": "view_johor"
                    },

                    {
                        "name": "selangor",
                        "command": "view_selangor"
                    },

                    {
                        "name": "melaka",
                        "command": "view_melaka"
                    },

                    {
                        "name": "kuala lumpur",
                        "command": "view_kl"
                    },

                    {
                        "name": "penang",
                        "command": "view_penang"
                    }
                ]
            };

            $.each(records.states, function (key, val) {
                $('#ul').append($('<li>').text('name: ' + val.name + ', command: ' + val.command));
            });
```

and this is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="ul"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Making very minor adjustments to your code,

```
var a = [];
$.each(result, function(index, val){
    for(var i=0; i < val.length; i++){
        var item = val[i];
        a.push(item);
    }
});
```

Now do something with all of the values in the array `a`.

EDIT:

In case that wasn't enough,

```
var list = $('<ui></ui>');
$.each(result.states, function(state) {
    var link = $('<a></a>').prop('href', state.command).text(state.name);
    ('<li></li>').append(link).appendTo(list);
});
```

`list` is the HTML you want (except for the name capitalization...I wasn't sure if the first letter should be capitalized, or the first letter of each word, so I left that alone).

Comment: -1   that change doesn't create html or steer OP in helpful direction

Comment: "I can access the data via console.log(item.name) and such, but I can't manipulate the data". Now he can manipulate the data.

Comment: @charlietfl, the responder here at worst deserves no vote, a negative vote is counter productive.  My opinion.

Comment: It stemmed from my misinterpretation of "JSON to list" as "JSON to array" instead of "JSON to HTML list" (which, BTW is a bit like saying "XML to Http"...very specific)