# work with list in jquery

Tags: jquery, django

with Django Rest Framework i "get" this data to localhost/api/data:

```
[{"date":"2018-01-02","time":"21:00","people":6},
{"date":"2018-01-11","time":"21:00","people":2},
{"date":"2018-01-04","time":"21:00","people":4},
{"date":"2018-01-06","time":"21:00","people":2},
{"date":"2018-01-06","time":"21:00","people":10},
{"date":"2018-01-03","time":"21:00","people":2},
{"date":"2018-01-06","time":"21:00","people":6},
{"date":"2018-01-06","time":"21:00","people":4},
{"date":"2018-01-06","time":"21:00","people":4}]
```

Now I want to pass them to chart.js charts, for example: 
- Line chart: from 1 to 30 January (to show all booked in 1st jan e.g) 
- Bar chart: the count filtered by week day (monday,...) 
 
- Bar chart: the count filtered by hour (21, 22, 23...)

I can take data in jquery function but I can't manipulate data...someone can help me?

Comment: You need to show the code you're using and the error you got.

Comment: Your data is in JSON format. You can read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/index.htm to know more about JSON. Once you can manipulate the data, rest of the things you can do easily by following documentation of Charts.js

Comment: I need an help on how to procede: it's better to make querys on django (python side) or inside jquery?

Comment: @Francesco if you need to show listing with this data you'll need to manipulate data in using jQuery.

Comment: @SushantPimple where I can find a tutorial on how to use lists and array in jQuery?

Comment: @SushantPimple jQuery doesn't manipulate arrays. This is a basic javascript mapping issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614970/how-to-create-list-from-json-array this might help you. (This doesn't include any Chart help though.)